# String replace in Sass

Tags: sass

Sass 3.2.1

How to replace in string some part of text? For example, remove from color #fefefe a dash #, to be fefefe.

Thanks!

Comment: String manipulation is currently not part of the core language, but it looks like it might be added in the future:  https://github.com/nex3/sass/pull/401

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple temporary solution (in my case for Mac):

```
$ git clone -b string_functions https://github.com/chriseppstein/sass
$ cd sass
$ sudo rake install

$ sudo mv /usr/bin/sass /usr/bin/sass.orig
$ sudo ln -s /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sass-3.2.0.alpha.0/bin/sass /usr/bin/sass
```

Comment: See the section "Adding Custom Functions" here: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/Sass/Script/Functions.html

Answer (score 37):

Here is a function that I just used!

**SCSS-FUNCTION**

```
/// Replace `$search` with `$replace` in `$string`
/// @author Hugo Giraudel
/// @param {String} $string - Initial string
/// @param {String} $search - Substring to replace
/// @param {String} $replace ('') - New value
/// @return {String} - Updated string
@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);

  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
  }

  @return $string;
}
```

**SCSS-USAGE:**

```
.selector {
  $string: 'The answer to life the universe and everything is 42.';
  content: str-replace($string, 'e', 'xoxo');
}
```

**SCSS-RESULT:**

```
.selector {
  content: "Thxoxo answxoxor to lifxoxo thxoxo univxoxorsxoxo and xoxovxoxorything is 42.";
}
```

[Source of SCSS-example](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/str-replace-function/)

**I use SASS with indented style**, so this is my conversion to get a color variable to replace in a background with data:href inline encoded css svg-image. The # needs to be url-encoded and I use global colors that only needs to be replaced in one place and simply just work!

**SASS-FUNCTION:**

```
@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '')
  $index: str-index($string, $search)
  @if $index
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace)
  @return $string
```

**SASS-USAGE:**

```
$color-blue-night: #172b47    
$icon-normal: str-replace('' + $color-blue-night, '#', '')
```

or for a clear example

```
   .test
     color: str-replace('' + $color-blue-night, '#', '')
```

**SASS-RESULT:**

```
.test {
  color: "172b47"; }
```

Comment: here is some more neat solution for getting color value without `#` :
```scss
 .test {
     color: str-replace(#{$color-blue-night}, '#', '')
  }
```