# Dynamic Spacing classes with SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

## Hi All!

I'm working with a sass file that has a looooooong set of hard-coded helper classes for padding and margins. Because we're working with `scss` here, this is redundant and can be solved with a sass function or something.
The trouble I'm having is actually writing the fancy `sass` to do the heavy lifting on this, because this requires... math. ***gasp***

---

It currently looks like this...

```
// Spacing
$spacer: 1rem;

// Margin Helpers
.m-0 {margin: 0;}
.m-1 {margin: ($spacer * .25);}
.m-2 {margin: ($spacer * .5);}
.m-3 {margin: ($spacer);}
.m-4 {margin: ($spacer * 1.5);}
.m-5 {margin: ($spacer * 3);}

.mt-0 {margin-top: 0;}
.mt-1 {margin-top: ($spacer * .25);}
.mt-2 {margin-top: ($spacer * .5);}
.mt-3 {margin-top: ($spacer);}
.mt-4 {margin-top: ($spacer * 1.5);}
.mt-5 {margin-top: ($spacer * 3);}

.ml-0 {margin-left: 0;}
.ml-1 {margin-left: ($spacer * .25);}
.ml-2 {margin-left: ($spacer * .5);}
.ml-3 {margin-left: ($spacer);}
.ml-4 {margin-left: ($spacer * 1.5);}
.ml-5 {margin-left: ($spacer * 3);}
```

Now imagine this ^^ with every side and spacing, all hard-coded, and repeated for padding helpers. Yeah, my jaw is on the ground too.

I'd like to turn the above mess, into a sass function, mixin, whatever would be ideal for this conundrum. I've scoured the depths of the internet and have found a lot that are either more complicated than necessary, or can't do the math I need. I'm not that experienced with scss functions and mixins so don't bully me just yet.

---

I was experimenting for like 3 hours until I finally gave up; during which I had found and was reading a few articles that may be able to help but I couldn't wrap my noodle of a brain around it quite, so I'll include those below.

[SASS Margin and Padding Helpers Loop. Generates .m-t-10 type helper classes.](https://gist.github.com/jacurtis/30da4bf9a6c9b9b5cc0aebac512ca7c9)

[How to dynamically build helper classes using SCSS](https://yolonerds.com/SCSS-repeated-helper-classes-with-5px-increment)

---

I'll give you a giant bear of a virtual hug if you can help me fix this disgrace of a sass file :)

Thanks in advance!
~ Josh

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's a pretty simple mixin to do what you want:

```scss
@mixin generate($prefix, $property) {
  // List of sizes to generate for each
  $sizes: [0, .25, .5, 1, 1.5, 3];
  // Spacing to multiply the sizes by
  $spacing: 1rem;
  
  // Loop through all of the sizes(we use @for rather than @each, as we want access to the index)
  @for $i from 1 through length($sizes) {
    // Get the size for the current index
    $size: nth($sizes, $i);
    
    // Create the rule
    .#{$prefix}-#{$i - 1} {
      #{$property}: $spacing * $size;
    }
  }
}
```

The usage of this mixin would look like so:

```scss
@include generate(ml, margin-left);
```

And would compile to:

```scss
.ml-0 {
  margin-left: 0rem;
}

.ml-1 {
  margin-left: 0.25rem;
}

.ml-2 {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

.ml-3 {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.ml-4 {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
}

.ml-5 {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}
```

You can play around with [this sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/6ee525b00c76a6d567cc574b496c710d).

When it comes to generating these for a large number of properties, you could take it another step, and use an `@each`:

```scss
$rules: [
  [ml, margin-left],
  [mt, margin-top],
  [mb, margin-bottom],
  [mr, margin-right],
];

@each $item in $rules {
  @include generate(nth($item, 1), nth($item, 2));
}
```

And [another sassmeister](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/18d6c98ea93edff56728d31d0dcde74b) for your convenience.

While you could go deeper and just loop over the `-top`, `-bottom`, etc so you just have to specify a property and everything else is generated, I don't know your use case, and you can figure it out.

Comment: Thanks bro! *Gives hug*

Answer (score 3):

Hello I'm not sure who still needs this but I think this is a slick way to do it

```
$spaceamounts: (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

@each $space in $spaceamounts {
    .m-#{$space} {
        margin: #{$space}rem;
    }

    .mx-#{$space} {
        margin-left: #{$space}rem;
        margin-right: #{$space}rem;
    }

    .my-#{$space} {
        margin-top: #{$space}rem;
        margin-bottom: #{$space}rem;

    }

    .ml-#{$space} {
        margin-left: #{$space}rem;
    }

    .mr-#{$space} {
        margin-right: #{$space}rem;
    }

    .mb-#{$space} {
        margin-bottom: #{$space}rem;
    }

    .mt-#{$space} {
        margin-top: #{$space}rem;
    }

    .p-#{$space} {
        padding: #{$space}rem;
    }

    .px-#{$space} {
        padding-left: #{$space}rem;
        padding-right: #{$space}rem;
    }

    .py-#{$space} {
        padding-top: #{$space}rem;
        padding-bottom: #{$space}rem;

    }

    .pl-#{$space} {
        padding-left: #{$space}rem;
    }

    .pr-#{$space} {
        padding-right: #{$space}rem;
    }

    .pb-#{$space} {
        padding-bottom: #{$space}rem;
    }

    .pt-#{$space} {
        padding-top: #{$space}rem;
    }
}
```

I would also like to shoutout brad traversy, he did it first in his own sass YouTube crashcourse video

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the following solution with SCSS.

Copy and paste it and compile it here into a CSS file:
http://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/

```
// With the help from
// https://gist.github.com/jacurtis/30da4bf9a6c9b9b5cc0aebac512ca7c9 
// and 
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12728634/string-replace-in-sass

// m: margin
// p: padding

// top: t
// right: r
// bottom: b
// left: l

// Between space (margin, padding) and the properties (top, right, bottom, left) and the number is a "-".
// The decimal point (".") is replaced by "_" and at the end stands the unit.

// Examples:

// .m-t-0_5rem --> margin-top: 0.5rem
// .p-b-2_25rem --> padding-bottom: 2.25rem
// .m-1_25rem --> margin: 1.25rem


/// Replace `$search` with `$replace` in `$string`
/// @author Hugo Giraudel
/// @param {String} $string - Initial string
/// @param {String} $search - Substring to replace
/// @param {String} $replace ('') - New value
/// @return {String} - Updated string
@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);

  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
  }

  @return $string;
}

$spaceamounts: (0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.25); // Change values according to your needs
$sides: (top, bottom, left, right, all); // Change sides according to your needs
$unit: rem; // Change unit according to your needs

@each $space in $spaceamounts {
  @each $side in $sides {
    @if $side == 'all' {
      .m-#{str-replace($space, '.', '_')}#{$unit} {
        margin: #{$space}$unit !important;
      }

      .p-#{str-replace($space, '.', '_')}#{$unit} {
        padding: #{$space}$unit !important;
      }
    } @else {
      .m-#{str-slice($side, 0, 1)}-#{str-replace($space, '.', '_')}#{$unit} {
        margin-#{$side}: #{$space}$unit !important;
      }

      .p-#{str-slice($side, 0, 1)}-#{str-replace($space, '.', '_')}#{$unit} {
        padding-#{$side}: #{$space}$unit !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Customizable:

- spaceamounts
- sides
- units

Create one CSS file per unit!